# Property 'push' does not exist on type number

Tags: typescript

I have an array, and I want it to store types of:

```
[[number, number], number[]]
```

But when I shift() elements from it, I get the error in the title. Why does TypeScript think my path variable is a number, and not an array of numbers?

```
export const myFunction = (coordinates: [number, number]): [[number, number]] => {
    const [i, j] = coordinates;
    const queue: [[number, number], number[]] = [[i, j], []]
    const [results, path] = queue.shift();
    path.push(results[0]);
    return path
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `queue.shift();`, you remove the first element of the queue array. This element is `[i, j]`, then you basically say `results = i` and `path = j`. 
Example below:

```js
export const myFunction = (coordinates: [number, number]): [[number, number]] => {
    const [i, j] = coordinates;
    const queue: [[number, number], number[]] = [[i, j], []]
    // get the first and second element of the array;
    const [results, path] = queue;
    // then remove coordinates;
    queue.shift(); 
    path.push(results[0]);
    return path
}
```

Comment: the queue will contain more than one element, so I need to use queue.shift().

Comment: But your question ". Why does TypeScript think my path variable is a number, and not an array of numbers?" is answered in my post.

Comment: no it isn't, the first element of my queue is [[i, j], []], not [i, j].

Comment: In your example you say `const queue = [[i, j], []]``, The queue is an array with two elements, [i, j] is the first element.

Comment: Oh sorry, the two elements were supposed to be combined into a single element like queue = [[[i, j], []], [[x, y], [1]]]